# Why does the convergence theorem of Fourier series hold in $L^2$ but fail in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

First consider a periodic continuous function $g \in C^0(\mathbb{T})$. We can find a sequence of trigonometric polynomials that converges uniformly to $g$ (e.g. convolution with Fejer kernels). Thus, the same sequence converges to $g$ in both $L^1$ and $L^2$ norm.

Now, $C^0(\mathbb{T})$ is dense in both $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ (wrt $L^1$ norm) and $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ (wrt $L^2$ norm). This together with the previous paragraph imply the linear span of $\{e^{in\theta}\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in both $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, so functions in both spaces can be written as trigonometric series.

However, it is well known that the Fourier series of every function $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ converges to $f$ in $L^2$ norm, whereas there exist functions in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ whose Fourier series diverge in $L^1$ norm (and in fact also diverge everywhere).

Why is that? Why doesn't the completeness of $\{e^{in\theta}\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ in $L^1$ imply the convergence of Fourier series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a differnce between the statements

a) linear span of $(x_n)$ is dense in the normed linear space $X$

b) every element of $X$ is of the form $\sum a_nx_n$.

It is true that the functions  $e^{2\pi i n\theta}$ span dense subspace of $L^{1}$ but it is not true that the Fourier series of any $L^{1}$ function  converges in $L^{1}$.

However a) and  b) become equivalent if $X$ is a Hilbert space and $(x_n)$ is an orthonormal set.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I know where I was wrong. Statement A implies for every $x \in X$, there exists a sequence of finite linear combinations $y_k = a^k_1 x_1 + a^k_2 x_2 + \cdots + a^k_{n_k} x_{n_k} $ such that $ ||y_k-x|| \rightarrow 0 $. But this doesn't imply $a^1_j = a^2_j = \cdots$, so we cannot conclude Statement B.

Comment: @user141240: Indeed.  As a related example, you might like to consider the difference between the two true statements "the polynomials are dense in $C([0,1])$" and "there are continuous functions which are not real analytic".